# Does high standard error and high r-square imply spurious regression?

Tags: regression, linear-regression, time-series, regression-analysis

Does a regression passed on time series data with one independent variable and one dependent variable which yields parameters with very high standard errors (t-values) and also a high r-squared imply that the regression results are spurious and that there is no real correlation between the variables?

The model is: $ln(y_t)=a+bln(x_t)$,
$R^2>0.95$

edit: just to clarify, these standard errors arent just high but are also high in comparison to their equivalent parameter estimates.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Can you please upload the data or the regression summary?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have any data. It was more of a theoretical question.

Comment: OK. So can you please write down the mathematical expression of the model? Is it $Y_t = \alpha_0 + \alpha_1 Y_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$ or $Y_t = \alpha_0 + \alpha_1 Y_{t-1} + \alpha_2X_t +  \epsilon_t$?

Comment: added it to the question

Comment: Not necessarily.  Taking logs will cause high errors for data points where x or y are close to zero.

Comment: ok i think that answers the question. did you want to answer it officially so i can accept the answer?